# IPMI: How to find the threshold values using ipmimonitoring-sensors.c

Tags: c, ipmi

I am writing an API to report IPMI hardware information queried by a Socket Daemon, the Socket Daemon is hosting on a client, and a remote server will send command to query the host hardware status.

I've successfully write an API, the API use FreeIPMI library, to get the CPU and M/B's temperature. After diving to ipmi-sensors source code, I found that is very difficult to skip output to stdout. To get the stdout, I use `dup(STDOUT_FILENO)` and redirect to a pipe, flush the pipe, parse the string content, extract information I need.

Everything is OK now, but I face another problem, I need to compile FreeIPMI as a static library.

I found a link [HOW to build freeipmi commands with static  libraries instead of shared libraries](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/freeipmi-devel/2014-08/msg00009.html), and the maintainer of FreeIPMI [Albert Chu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1397356/albert-chu) said that

```
./configure CFLAGS="-static"
```

Build static libraries successfully, but fail to build the ipmi-sensors, there are many compiler error. So frustrated.

After that, I find another file in FreeIPMI project folder [ipmimonitoring-sensors.c](https://www.gnu.org/software/freeipmi/ipmimonitoring-sensors.c), compile with command

```
gcc -o ipmimonitoring-sensors ipmimonitoring-sensors.c -lipmimonitoring
```

Yes, it works.

```
sudo ./ipmimonitoring-sensors 
Record ID, Sensor Name, Sensor Number, Sensor Type, Sensor State, Sensor Reading, Sensor Units, Sensor Event/Reading Type Code, Sensor Event Bitmask, Sensor Event String
3, CPU0_TEMP, 33, Temperature, Nominal, 46.00, C, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
12, DIMM_P0_B0, 4, Temperature, Nominal, 39.00, C, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
13, DIMM_P0_B1, 5, Temperature, Nominal, 40.00, C, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
59, P12V, 64, Voltage, Nominal, 12.06, V, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
60, P5V, 65, Voltage, Nominal, 4.99, V, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
61, P3V3, 66, Voltage, Nominal, 3.27, V, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
62, P5V_STBY, 67, Voltage, Nominal, 4.99, V, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
64, P_VBAT, 69, Voltage, Nominal, 3.22, V, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
65, P_VCCIN_P0, 70, Voltage, Nominal, 1.80, V, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
67, P_1V2_BXD, 72, Voltage, Nominal, 1.23, V, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
71, P_1V05_BXD, 76, Voltage, Nominal, 1.06, V, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
72, P_1V5_BXD, 77, Voltage, Nominal, 1.53, V, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
73, P_VCCSCFUSESUS, 78, Voltage, Nominal, 1.72, V, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
74, P_VCCKRHV_BXD, 79, Voltage, Nominal, 1.32, V, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
136, CPU0_FAN, 96, Fan, Nominal, 2700.00, RPM, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
185, CPU0, 156, Processor, Nominal, N/A, N/A, 6Fh, 80h, 'Processor Presence detected'
202, MB_TEMP1, 51, Temperature, Nominal, 50.00, C, 1h, C0h, 'OK'
205, SEL, 152, Event Logging Disabled, Nominal, N/A, N/A, 6Fh, 0h, 'OK'
```

But, how can I get the threshold values as `ipmi-sensors -v`, I know that will report `Nominal`, `Warning` and `Critical`. But I'd like to report `Low`, `High`, not just only `OK` event.

```
Entity Instance Type: Physical Entity
Event/Reading Type Code: 1h
Lower Critical Threshold: 0.000000 C
Upper Critical Threshold: 60.000000 C
Lower Non-Critical Threshold: 5.000000 C
Upper Non-Critical Threshold: 55.000000 C
Lower Non-Recoverable Threshold: N/A
Upper Non-Recoverable Threshold: N/A
Sensor Min. Reading: -128.000000 C
Sensor Max. Reading: 127.000000 C
Normal Min.: 0.000000 C
Normal Max.: 54.000000 C
Nominal Reading: 35.000000 C
Sensor Reading: 50.000000 C
Sensor Event: 'OK'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

FreeIPMI maintainer here.  I'm afraid threshold information isn't available in the ipmimonitoring library.  The main purpose of the library was to abstract that information away from the user.

The threshold information for each sensor can be retrieved by getting the information from the SDR, which you can use the libfreeipmi SDR library for.  Ipmi monitoring does provide you w/ the SDR record ID associated with each sensor read, so that you can map the sensor to the right SDR record ID.